# Continuous non differentiable functions :)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, special-functions

I was searching for functions like Weierstrass (continuous but differentiable nowhere), but I haven't found any. If you could tell me some that would be great.
Also, I would like to find some continuous functions with dense maximums.

This information would be very helpful for a research I'm doing in my university.

Thanks!

Comment: yes :C and the only case I found for the first one, was Weierstrass.

Comment: After my own mentioning of the Weierstrass function, MJD responded with this link: http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/weierstrass.pdf
on my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140428/continuous-versus-differentiable/140724#140724

Comment: Weierstrass's function can be generalized. Or are you looking for some radically different construction?

Comment: @studiosus lol bing.

Comment: @vonbrand radically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Johan_Thim/publication/255669824_Continuous_Nowhere_Differentiable_Functions_MS_Thesis) looks to me as a very thorough compendium.