# Find an equation of the tangent line to a graph

Tags: calculus

Consider the graph defined by

$$y = \dfrac{x - 3}{x - 5}$$

(a) Use the definition of the derivative to find the slope of the tangent line to the graph at the point $(6, 3)$.

(b) Find an equation of the tangent line to the graph at the point $(6, 3)$.

Comment: Show your working please.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45336/relation-between-the-tangent-to-a-curve-and-the-first-derivative-of-a-function

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the derivative , which gives the slope is $$y_0'=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}$$
The equation of the tangent line is $$y-y_0=y'_0(x-x_0)$$
Can you now continue?

Comment: I thank you for your help.Using this definition I find the slope of the tangent line to be 0.4 and the resulting equation to be y = 0.4x + 0.6

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac{(x-5)\dfrac {d}{dx}(x-3)-(x-3)\dfrac {d}{dx}(x-5)}{(x-5)^2}$$

$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac{(x-5)-(x-3)}{(x-5)^2}$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}_{(6,3)}=\dfrac{-2}{(x-5)^2}$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}_{(6,3)}=\dfrac{-2}{(6-5)^2}$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}_{(6,3)}=-2$$

slope of tangent at $(6,3)$=$-2$

### b)

equation of tangent :  $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$

(where $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point on line and m is slope)

$$y-3=-2(x-6)$$
$$2x+y=15$$

Comment: Thankyou so much :) Rockin answer!

Comment: @Tangles my pleasure.Nothing rocking Just an starter question.

Comment: what can I say.... I'm a freshie in the world of calculus ;P

Comment: keep continue buddy

Comment: This can also be greatly simplified by the observation that $\frac{x-3}{x-5}=1+\frac{2}{x-5}$.

Comment: @ZettaSuro but using differentiation is standard way to do so.

Comment: Yes. And taking the derivative of the above expression is much easier, is what I'm saying.

Comment: okay I got it.that's why downvote.

Comment: No, I'm not the one who downvoted, your answer is still correct so I'm not sure what that was for.